# How do I integrate Liquibase within an existing CI/CD pipeline in large organization?

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, liquibase, continuous-deployment

We are working in a very big organization, many Databases (of many types), many schemas, many users.

1. Does LB has to work with some  Source Control (for locking the files
   when many users exist in the organization and using the same DB,
   same Schema, etc)?
2. What is the best practice of working with LB in a very big
   organization, many concurrent users?
3. Can SQLCL general sql format type or just xml format type?
4. Is there some integration with SQL Developer? I mean, suppose a user
   changes an objects via sql developer, what happens then?

Comment: Is this some marketing post? You work with Liquibase, how difficult was it to get that information internally. The responder also works for the same company (Lil bit of google search and it shows both of you are from the same location). I am not against sharing information, but Is StackOverflow now being used to promote products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We get this type of question all the time, after folks get a handle of how to automate DB changes, next step is typically to add it into an existing CI/CD workflow.

1. Yes, Liquibase works with any source control.  Most users are using
   Git.  But you can use Git, TFS, SVN, CVS... Once you are up and
   running with Liquibase, you just need to make sure that your scripts
   are in source control and you are good to go.
2. Besides 3rd party source control tools, Liquibase has tracking tables called "DATABASECHANGELOG" tables that keep track of the changes applied to your database when using Liquibase deployments.
   Here is some more information about getting started and How Liquibase Works. https://www.liquibase.org/get_started/how-lb-works.html
3. Liquibase has one more table that it uses internally called "DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK" table.
   This table was designed to prevent multiple Liquibase users running deployments concurrently - potentially leaving the Database in a bad state.  Once the Liquibase deployment (the liquibase update command) is done, the "DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK" will allow the next Liquibase user to deploy.
4. You can use both SQL and XML formats (or even JSON and YAML formats).

   - When using SQL, you have a few options:

     - Best option is to use Formatted SQL changeLogs https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html
       https://www.liquibase.org/get_started/quickstart_sql.html
     - You can use plain raw SQL files referenced from an XML changeLog
     - https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html
   - When using XML, can find all the available change types (also called changeSets) available in the following page (on the left of the page)
     https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/
   - XML changeLog are more agnostic and sometimes can be used for different Database platforms when doing migrations.  Also, many of the change types in XML have the ability to be rolled back automatically.  The reason that this is possible with XML is because Liquibase uses it own built in functions to figure out inverse statements like "create table" to be "drop table".
   - For each of those changeSets you can find out if they are auto rollback eligible (at the bottom of the page).  For example, create table changeSet will be Auto Rollback = yes. 
     https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_table.html